# (SQL Beginner Question) help understanding how HAVING and GROUP BY are applied

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregation

I'm working on practice problems with the Northwinds practice database in SQL Server and I just cannot understand how this solution works. Any help explaining it would be greatly appreciated (any critiques of my code efficiency or readability are welcome - I am a beginner).

The practice problem comes in two questions.

The first is: define customers that have made at least 1 order with a value equal to or greater than $10,000 in 2016.

For this I wrote:

```
SELECT
    o.CustomerID,
    c.CompanyName,
    o.OrderID,
    SUM(d.UnitPrice*d.Quantity) AS 'TotalOrderAmount'
FROM 
    Orders AS o
JOIN
    Customers AS c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
JOIN
    OrderDetails AS d ON d.OrderID = o.OrderID
WHERE
    YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 2016
GROUP BY
    o.CustomerID, c.CompanyName, o.OrderID
HAVING
    SUM(d.UnitPrice * d.Quantity) >= 10000
ORDER BY
    TotalOrderAmount DESC
```

The second question is: define customers that have orders totaling $15,000 or more in 2016.

The solution I wrote with some help from the back of the book is:

```
SELECT
    c.CustomerID,
    c.CompanyName,
    SUM(d.UnitPrice*d.Quantity) AS 'TotalOrderAmount'
FROM 
    Orders AS o
JOIN
    Customers AS c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
JOIN
    OrderDetails AS d ON d.OrderID = o.OrderID
WHERE
    YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 2016
GROUP BY
    c.CustomerID, c.CompanyName
HAVING
    SUM(d.UnitPrice * d.Quantity) >= 15000
ORDER BY
    TotalOrderAmount DESC
```

I just don't understand how presenting what looks like a SUM statement of an individual order translates to asking what a customer's yearly total is. The book specifically mentioned changing the GROUP BY levels so I just did it but I'm still not sure how it is the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand what it is you don't understand here. What, specifically, is the thing you are unclear on here?

Comment: Look CLOSELY at the GROUP BY clause. What is the difference? One has OrderID and one doesn't. So what difference does that make to the value computed by SUM?

Comment: The first query is not entirely correct, it will give the same customers multiple times if they have multiple such orders. Aside: `YEAR(...) = ` is inefficient, it's normally faster to use `date >= 'yyyy-01-01' AND date < 'nxtyear-01-01'`

Comment: @Larnu The second question want's yearly combined order totals greater than or equal to $15,000 but in HAVING it looks to me like it is just looking for orders over $15,000 not a year end total sales of $15,000.

Comment: @Larnu Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question then. I was thrown off a bit when the answer section said "All that was necessary here was to comment out references in the Select clause and the Group By clause to OrderID. By doing that, we're grouping at the customer level, and not at the Order Level."

Comment: @Charlieface The GROUP BY c.CustomerName, c.CustomerID statement wouldn't push all of a customer's orders together? Is there an exception in the way this is structured? Why would you use the  date >= 'yyyy-01-01' AND date < 'nxtyear-01-01' instead of YEAR(....)? Is is a machine process thing? On just the surface YEAR(....) seems more simple.

Comment: The first query also groups by orderId, so you end up with one row for every order. Really you want to group only by customer, then use some kind conditional aggregation like `COUNT(CASE WHEN d.UnitPrice * d.Quantity THEN 1 END)` For dates: using the `YEAR` function means the compiler cannot use an index (it has no way of working out what the function does in reality), whereas a date interval is understandable to it and it can do a range seek on the index

Answer (score 0):

Try this: remove the `HAVING` clause, and filter the results to a single customer and company, so you can look at them more closely:

```sql
SELECT
    o.CustomerID,
    c.CompanyName,
    o.OrderID,
    SUM(d.UnitPrice*d.Quantity) AS TotalOrderAmount
FROM 
    Orders AS o
JOIN
    Customers AS c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
JOIN
    OrderDetails AS d ON d.OrderID = o.OrderID
WHERE
    YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 2016
    -- pick a customer and company that gives you some orders
    AND c.CustomerID = 12345
    AND c.CompanyName = 'Acme Corp'
GROUP BY
    o.CustomerID, c.CompanyName, o.OrderID
```

You should see a different `TotalOrderAmount` for each `OrderID`.

Now remove `o.OrderID` from the `SELECT` clause and the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT
    o.CustomerID,
    c.CompanyName,
    SUM(d.UnitPrice*d.Quantity) AS TotalOrderAmount
FROM 
    Orders AS o
JOIN
    Customers AS c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
JOIN
    OrderDetails AS d ON d.OrderID = o.OrderID
WHERE
    YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 2016
    -- use the same filters as before
    AND c.CustomerID = 12345
    AND c.CompanyName = 'Acme Corp'
GROUP BY
    o.CustomerID, c.CompanyName
```

You should now see just one row, and its `TotalOrderAmount` will be all the previous `TotalOrderAmount` values added together. That's because rows which were previously separate because they had different `OrderID` values are now combined into the same group. When we calculate the `SUM` of that new larger group, it includes all the values from those previous groups.

The `HAVING` clause just looks at the same equation as the `TotalOrderAmount` column, and uses it to filter *whole groups* from the result.